# How to set up DISPLAY variable for WSL2 of ubuntu 20?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sed

I have a WSL2 with ubuntu 20. In most posts, setting up `DISPLAY` environmental variable to access windows X11 server is made through WSL localhost address in `~/.bashrc`

```
$ export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0
```

or

```
$ export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf |grep nameserver| sed 's/nameserver //'):0
```

However, these commands will find the WSL2 machine localhost IP that differs from host machine localhost.

For Me, to make xlaunch  X11 server works properly, I have to set `DISPLAY` every time the host localhost IP is changed using  cmd `ipconfig` command.

Is there a way to set `DISPLAY` to host machine localhost before the start of  WSL2. For instance, through windows `%USERPROFILE%\.wslconfig` file.

Comment: Perhaps [Running WSL GUI Apps on Windows 10](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242) is useful? `export DISPLAY=$(ip route|awk '/^default/{print $3}'):0.0` or one of the other two examples in the article.

Comment: As explained in https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242, do not forget to allow VcXsrv in the Windows firewall settings: Windows Security -> Firewall & network protection -> Allow an app through firewall -> make sure VcXsrv has both public and private checked.

Answer (score 5):

Note that this question is a bit (but not totally) outdated.  There are now multiple answers to this question, depending on your Windows version and DNS settings.

For completeness, I'll also cover WSL1, even though the question itself was asking about WSL2.

- ***WSL2***

  - *What *doesn't* work in Windows 10 (and why):*

    In Windows 10 with Ubuntu under WSL2, you had to use a third-party X server in order to run graphical apps.  Since that X server was running in *Windows* (rather than Ubuntu), it's on a separate network and needs an IP address.

    On Windows 10, the following would *not* work:

    ```
    export DISPLAY=:0.0
    # or export DISPLAY=:0
    ```
  - *Windows 10 using mDNS with WSL's DNS Resolver:*

    I usually use and recommend:

    ```
    export DISPLAY=$(hostname).local:0
    ```

    This uses mDNS to obtain the correct address, per my [write-up on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/11810933) on the topic.

    Note that this assumes that you are using the built-in WSL DNS resolver.  If you override this with your own DNS settings, then it probably won't work, since your DNS server probably won't know the correct IP address for your Windows host.  In that case, proceed to ...
  - *Windows 10 with custom DNS Resolver:*

    If you have changed your `/etc/resolv.con`, then mDNS probably won't work.  In that case, try the technique in [@ChaiAng's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418823/1165986).  It should work even when not using WSL's resolver.  However, it's a bit slower (2 seconds or so for me), so I wouldn't recommend putting it in a startup file such as `~/.bashrc`.
  - *Windows 11 using WSLg:*

    Under Windows 11, WSL2 can run GUI applications using the WSLg feature.  It runs in the same network-space as WSL itself, so under Windows 11, we're back to the following being the correct `DISPLAY` setting:

    ```
    export DISPLAY=:0
    ```

    Note that this is set for you automatically in your Ubuntu/WSL2 session by the WSL `/init`, so there shouldn't be any reason to set it manually except in some special circumstances.
- ***WSL1***

  - *For both Windows 10 and 11:*

    Under WSL1, Ubuntu itself is running under the same network as Windows, so in that case, you'll use:

    ```
    export DISPLAY=:0
    ```

    Note that you will need a third-party X server with WSL1, regardless of whether you are running Windows 10 or 11.  WSLg is only supported under WSL2.

Comment: In your write up, you mention "bind to 0.0.0.0" as an option. Could you clarify how to do that? I tried setting DISPLAY=0.0.0.0 and that did not work. I'm using pycharm and it doesn't run $(hostname).local, I believe it needs a string "DISPLAY=SOMEIPADDRESS"

Comment: `export DISPLAY=$(hostname):0.0` works for me running VcXsrv

Comment: @AlexanderVasiljev Cool!  At first glance based on a quick test, it looks like the resolver may have changed to allow this.  Ok, second glance - It seems to also involve the automatic generation of `/etc/hosts`, which now has a mapping of your Windows hostname to `127.0.1.1`.  I don't recall anything in the WSL release notes about this, but I might not have made the connection ... Off to skim back through them ;-).  Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

You can test it will xeyes.  If you don't have xeyes

```
sudo apt install x11-apps
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, though the OP's method did work.  Connection Refused.

Comment: @RoyTruelove  Do you know what the DISPLAY variable evaluated to?

Comment: Worked for me. It somehow hanged plasma-desktop and trying to come back to my opened windows I tried all kinds of things but seting DISPLAY to ":0.0" saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me.

```
$ export DISPLAY=$(host `hostname --long` | grep -oP '(\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}' | tail -1 | awk '{ print $NF }' | tr -d '\r')
```

This seems to find the IP address I need for my X window apps to work.

Comment: Good method - I hadn't seen that one before.  There's a simpler version, but it requires the built-in WSL resolver, which some people need to override (I believe the OP did).  I'm fairly sure yours will work even when not using the built-in WSL resolver.

Comment: Do you mean using the "$(hostname).local". I saw that but couldnt get it to work with the Xserver which is running on the host. ie. when I do a $ telnet "$(hostname).local" 6000 ... which is the XServer port, I cant reach it. Whereas it would when I used the above. I think it's a firewall problem which I cannot play around with cos it's a work computer and everything is kind of locked down.

Comment: Right - Do you override `/etc/resolv.conf`?  If so, then the `$(hostname).local` (mDNS lookup) won't work.  I wrote up a separate answer on it, but mentioned that your technique should be used if the mDNS name can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a WSL2 Ubuntu on WIN10 variation, where the `/etc/resolv.conf` information cannot be used to grab useful details because I need that file to hold some "alternative" DNS information.

So therefore I rely on accessing host machine (IP) info via calling the `ipconfig.exe` (note the `.exe` so the) Windows program from WSL2 and storing that as `DISPLAY`.

So I put something like this in my `.zshrc` (or `.bashrc` or other shell rc) file.

```
DISPLAY=$(ipconfig.exe | grep -oP '(\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}' | tail -2 | head -1 | awk '{ print $NF }')
export DISPLAY=$DISPLAY:0.0
```

Adjust the `n` in the `tail -n | head -1` commands part accordingly to make it return the `IPv4 address` of the `Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL)` returned by `ipconfig.exe`